# spring-boot user session not added to context after login when switching from https to http

Tags: authentication, redirect, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-session

I have a spring-boot 1.3.5.RELEASE with spring security 4.1.0.RELEASE application  and the users are getting redirected to the login page after the first time they input username and password. The second time they input the username and password, it works fine.

The scenario is as follows:

1. users gets redirected to login page (which is using HTTPS)
2. user inputs username and password and presses enter
3. user gets redirected again to the login page as if he didn't input username and password
4. user inputs username and password again and presses enter
5. user gets redirected to home page (HTTP)

This happens every time the user tries to login.

**Edit: this does not happen when I restart the spring-boot application or when a I open a new browser session (chrome person). Seems like it happens only after logging out**

I tracked this down to spring's user session fixation, but don't know how to fix this.

How my configuration looks like:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .headers().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/auth/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/login")
            .failureUrl("/auth/login-secure?loginFailed=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/defaultEntry")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/auth/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/logout-success")
        .deleteCookies("jsessionid", "JSESSIONID")
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionFixation().none()
        .and()
        .anonymous().principal(ANONYMOUS_USER)

        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/websocket/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/auth/login", "/auth/login-secure", "/auth/login-oauth2").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth/external-logout").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/index.jsp").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/defaultEntry").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**/*").hasRole("T2K_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/client/**/*").authenticated();

    // we set the redirect port for https for dev environment. Production environment has the connectors configured in Tomcat's server.xml
    if (Arrays.asList(environment.getActiveProfiles()).contains(SpringProfiles.DEVELOPMENT)) {
        http.portMapper()
                .http(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("server.port")))
                .mapsTo(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("server.https.port")));
    }

    http.requiresChannel()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").requiresSecure()
            .anyRequest().requiresInsecure();
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private CGSUserDetails currentUser;

    @Autowired
    private Authentication authentication;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {
        return "redirect:login-secure";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth/login-secure", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginSecure() {
        if (authentication.isAuthenticated() && !ANONYMOUS_USER.equals(authentication.getName())) {
            return "redirect:/defaultEntry";
        } else {
            return "auth/login"; // get /auth/login.jsp
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String openHomePage() throws Exception {
        if (authentication.isAuthenticated() && !ANONYMOUS_USER.equals(authentication.getName())) {
            return "index";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/defaultEntry";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/defaultEntry", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String defaultEntry() {
        if (authentication.isAuthenticated() && !ANONYMOUS_USER.equals(authentication.getName())) {
            return "redirect:/home";
        } else {
            return "redirect:login";
        }
    }
}
```

The User and authentication beans:

```
@Bean(name = "userDetails")
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public UserDetails userDetails() {
    return AuthenticationHolder.getUserDetails();
}

@Bean(name = "authentication")
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public Authentication authentication() {
    return AuthenticationHolder.getAuthentication();
}
```

What I found out during debugging:

1. On loading the page the browser redirects to `login` over HTTPS
2. After the user inputs the username and password and presses enter, the browser tries to load `defaultEntry` over HTTPS, then gets redirected to `defaultEntry` over HTTP.
   I put a filter and an application listener to track what is happening and I see the following
   after pressing enter on login:

> onApplicationEvent - session authenticated for user: admin, sessionId: 80CDEA048679E189485FE0F4597BE2E8
>
> (TestFilter.java:34) URL accessed: https://localhost:8443/auth/login; Current user: Annonymous
>
> (TestFilter.java:34) URL accessed: https://localhost:8443/auth/login-secure; Current user: Annonymous
>
> (TestFilter.java:34) URL accessed: https://localhost:8443/auth/login-strings; Current user: Annonymous

3. The user got redirected to login over HTTP, which redirects to the secure login over HTTPS
4. User inputs username and password again and presses enter
5. `defaultEntry` now gets loaded directly over HTTP (no more first try over HTTPS) and the home page loads

> onApplicationEvent - session authenticated for user: admin, sessionId: 933F361668CFF01EBCC0DF88763D4DF4
>
> (TestFilter.java:34) URL accessed: http://localhost:8000/defaultEntry; Current user: CGSUserDetailsImpl{firstName='admin', lastName='admin', email='admin@mycompany.com'}

I also tried changing the sessionFixation mode and scope, but the user and authorization didn't get autowired anymore in other configuration.

How can I make it redirect correctly to home the first time?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed it.
In my case, the issue was caused by the logout form.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/logout-success", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logoutSuccess() {
    return "auth/logout-success";
}
```

This was loading the following .jsp

```
<head>
    <title>Logout</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "login";
    </script>
</body>
```

I removed this .jsp and changed the logout mapping to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/logout-success", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logoutSuccess() {
    return "redirect:/defaultEntry";
}
```